# How to check if Ajax Control Toolkit CollapsiblePanelExtender is collapsed using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajaxcontroltoolkit, collapsiblepanelextender

I've the following ASP.NET code:

```
<div id="pnlFiltros" class="card">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlFiltrosHeader" runat="server" CssClass="card-header bg-verdepetrobras text-white">
        Filtros (<asp:Label ID="lblTextFiltros" runat="server" />)
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlFiltrosContent" runat="server" CssClass="card-body">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label>Chave / Nome</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtChaveNome" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <asp:Button ID="btPesquisar" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Pesquisar" OnClick="btPesquisar_Click" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>

<ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpExtFiltros" runat="server" TargetControlID="pnlFiltrosContent" CollapseControlID="pnlFiltrosHeader" ExpandControlID="pnlFiltrosHeader"
    Collapsed="false" TextLabelID="lblTextFiltros" CollapsedText="Clique para exibir..." ExpandedText="Clique para esconder..."
    CollapsedSize="0"></ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
```

How can I check if Ajax Control Toolkit CollapsiblePanelExtender is collapsed using JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

There are few function that you can access via given behavior id

```
<ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="LimitedByTypePanelExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="LimitedByTypePanel" BehaviorID="bhvLimitedByType" Collapsed="true">
</ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
```

if you check the object `$find('bhvLimitedByType')` in chrome console you can see below and more methods in the prototype

[image]

So according to this, you can use to check whether panel is collapsed or not.

```
var isLimitedByCollapsed = $find('bhvLimitedByType').get_Collapsed();
```

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was to get the height of "pnlFiltrosContent". If it's 0px, the panel is collapsed.

```
            if ($('#<%=pnlPerfilContent.ClientID%>').css("height") == "0px")
                alert("Is collapsed");
```